# Create test cube based on existing cube data (but much larger)

Tags: testing, ssas, cube

Is it possible to create a large cube based on existing cube data?

We'd like to test the performance of certain tools in combination with SSAS and currently do not have any cubes large enough.

e.g. We have a year's worth of data and want to expand it to be 10 year's worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly I have created my own scripts for growing test data.

I have used Adventure Works as a base for names, address etc, also I have used [Red Gate's data generator](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Generator/index.htm) (was working at a place that had the full Red Gate product suite, you can download an evaluation copy to test it out).

Might be worth writing your own scripts. Then you can tweak the generation scripts to generate additional versions for testing.

Answer (score 1):

To increase the size of your data you need to write custom scripts to copy it.  There is no automatic way to "grow data" in SQL.